# Return False if the same input is given more than once

Tags: python-3.x

I want to return False if the same input is given:

```
first_answer = input("select square number 1: ")
second_answer = input("select square number 2: ")
third_answer = input("select square number 3: ") 

if first_answer == second_answer or first_answer == third_answer or 
second_answer == first_answer or second_answer == third_answer or 
third_answer == first_answer or third_answer == second_answer:
print("don\'t repeat squares")
```

Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you like this:

> ```
> set_answers = set()
> set_answers.add(input("select square number 1: "))
> set_answers.add(input("select square number 2: "))
> set_answers.add(input("select square number 3: "))
> if len(set_answers) < 3:
>     print("don\'t repeat squares")
> ```

?

The **TRICK**: `set()` stores only unique elements, so adding same value again to a `set` doesn't change the number of its elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```py
count = 3
answers = []
for i in range(0, count):
    answers[i] = input("select square number " + str(i+1) + ": "

for i in range(0, count-1):
    for j in range(i+1, count):
        if answers[i] == answers[j]:
            print("don\'t repeat squares")
```

It is (almost) always easier to abstract this kind of thing by using loops and arrays (or sets, or tuples) than to program each variable by hand.

`answers` is a list here, and the first loop inputs the data into the array.  Note that you can easily change the amount of data you want simply by modifying the initial value of `count` -- this will change everything else as well (including the input messages!).

The second loop is actually a nested pair of for loops in order to generate all of the (relevant) pairs of data items to compare.  Note that the first loop stops one short of the last element and that the second loop starts one after whatever the value of the first loop is.  This is in order to avoid incorrectly comparing an element with itself.

---

CLARIFICATION:

`[]` is an empty list.  A list in Python is just an ordered list of elements that can be accessed by their position (index) in the list.  Indexes start from 0.  (there are good reasons for this)

In general, the `range` function returns all the integers in the given range that *includes* the lower bound (the left argument) and *does not include* the upper bound (the right argument).  (there are good reasons for this too)